# How to submit a form inside a <div> into the same <div>

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, ajax

```
I have 2 <div> in my JSP 

<div id="searchCriteria">
// included one search criteria JSP with search button. 
</div>
<div id="searchResult">
// included search result jsp with <previous> <next> navigation links
</div>
```

Question : on click of previous & next navigation link, i want to submit the form available inside the `div` (#searchResult) to the same div itself without disturbing the other `div`

Any help ?

`document.querySelector('#searchResult form').submit()` - tried this but it submits the form to the whole content. But i want the submit to happen only inside the `searchResult` `div`

Comment: I think you'll want to use AJAX to submit your form and then update the div as needed with JS.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion @mykaf. but my problem is, first time when the searchResult div is loaded, am doing some manipulations and assigning values to hidden fields which i need to reuse upon submitting to the same div. This is where am stuck

Comment: Can you elaborate? I'm not understanding why `some manipulations and assigning values to hidden fields which I need to reuse upon submitting to he same div` is causing problems. What's preventing you from reusing those?

Answer (score 0):

You can't target a `<div>` element with a form submission. `<form>` elements have a [`target` attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/form#method) but that only targets windows, tabs, and frames.

You could replace the `<div>` with an `<iframe>` and then put the `<form>` in a separate document which you load into the frame by default. (You won't need the `target` attribute since the default behaviour targets the current frame/window/tab).

You could also use a [submit](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLFormElement/submit_event) event [listener](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener) to intercept the form submission, [prevent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/preventDefault) the normal behaviour of the form, capture the data in the form using a [FormData](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData/FormData) object, submit it via [Ajax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/AJAX) using [the Fetch API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API), then [replace the content](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/innerHTML) of the `<div>` with the result.

---

That said, it would be more typical to replace the *whole* page and include the data needed to preserve the searchCriteria in the pagination links so you can recreate it when the page is loaded.